# I have a 50 GB storage plan for a previous phone that I still pay for. How do I make it cover my new phone?

Tags: storage

I had  an iPhone now I have a Samsung. I am still paying for my storage plan for the iPhone. How do I get my new phone covered with this plan?

Answer (score 3):

It's assumed you mean an iCloud storage plan and not a storage plan sold/supported by your carrier (i.e. AT&T has [Personal Cloud](https://www.att.com/features/att-personal-cloud/)).

iCloud storage is tied to your Apple ID, not to the device itself.  So, all devices that you have signed into with your AppleID, will have access to that storage pool.  Once you sign out, the device will no longer have access to it.  Since you're using a Samsung (Android) device, the only way to access iCloud is via the iCloud Website (https://icloud.com).  If you no longer need this, you simply have to cancel it as there's no Android app for iCloud.

If it is a plan through your carrier, to move your service you would need to contact them for support.

Comment: I think accessing iCloud.com on a mobile device does not work. Correct me if I am wrong, but I used to try this a couple of years ago when I had an Android device

Comment: There's no Android app so the only way to access it on an Android would be via  a browser. It's a royal pain, but it can be done.